# Creating Google Sitemap from Database

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to create a sitemap for google from info supplied from my database, everything works except when I try and use image:image and image:loc I get this error in my xml file:

This page contains the following errors:

> error on line 8 at column 17: Namespace prefix image on image is not
>   defined

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

My Code:

```
//create the xml document
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

//create the root element
$root = $xmlDoc->appendChild(
          $xmlDoc->createElement('urlset'));
$root->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createAttribute("xmlns"))->appendChild(
      $xmlDoc->createTextNode('http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'));       

foreach($r as $spirit){

$urlSpirit = 'http://urlroot.com' . $spirit['Category'] . '/' .  $spirit['subcategory'] . '/' . $spirit['permName'];
$imgSpirit = 'http://urlroot.com' . $spirit['picture'];
  //create a url element
  $urlTag = $root->appendChild(
              $xmlDoc->createElement("url"));

  //create the loc element
  $urlTag->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createElement("loc", $urlSpirit));

  //create the changefreq element
  $urlTag->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createElement("changefreq", 'weekly'));

  //create the priority element
  $urlTag->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createElement("priority", '1.0'));

  //create the lastmod element
  $urlTag->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createElement("lastmod", $spirit['lastReview']));


  //create the img element
  $imgTag = $urlTag->appendChild(
              $xmlDoc->createElement('image:image'));

   $imgTag->appendChild(
      $xmlDoc->createElement("image:loc", $imgSpirit));
}

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

//make the output pretty
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;

$xmlDoc->save('test.xml');
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What question are you asking? The error is because you are creating an element `image:image` (and subsequently `image:loc`) but haven't set up the `image` namespace prefix.

Comment: But I am not trying to setup a namespace I am just following google example. I guess my question would be how do I make it not think its a namespace and just print that.

Comment: You aren't following it closely enough. Any element of the form `prefix:local_part` are using a namespace prefix, and for at least some tools you need to declare those. [Google's documentation of images in sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636) contains the relevant namespace prefix declaration for you.

Comment: ahhh I see now I must of missed that thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your missing the image namespace so you need to add this:

```
$root->appendChild(
    $xmlDoc->createAttribute("xmlns:image"))->appendChild(
        $xmlDoc->createTextNode('http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1'));
```

As someone mentioned you can see this in the [Google documentation of images](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636).